# flex 4 datefield does not dispatch clear event

Tags: events, flex4, datefield

here is my datefield:

```
<mx:DateField id="date" 
    formatString="DD-MM-YYYY" selectableRange="{DTselectableRange}" 
    change="handleChange()" editable="true"  clear="dateCleared(event)"/>
```

i want to detect clear event, adobe ref say:

> clear Event is dispatched when the user
>   selects 'Clear' (or 'Delete') from the
>   text context menu.

but dateCleared function in never called...I need it beacause I have to set selectedDate to null when user delete it...

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that mx.controls.DateField does not dispatch a `clear` event when selecting "Delete" from the text content menu.  I've also had no luck getting a `clear` event to be dispatched for editable `mx.controls.TextInput` and `spark.components.TextInput`.  Hmm....

What you can do is handle a change in the value of the control in your `handleChange` event listener and set your `selectedDate` value there.

Something like this:

```
private var selectedDate:Date;

private function handleChange(date:Date):void {
    if (date == null) {
        selectedDate = null;
    }       
    // your existing handleChange code here
}
```

Also, I would change this:

```
<mx:DateField change="handleChange()" />
```

to this

```
<mx:DateField change="handleChange(DateField(event.target).selectedDate)" />
```